# GWT application/eclipse plugin crashes JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm trying to set up the GWT framework. I'm following the quick start at: http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html. OS is Ubuntu 8.04. I create a new application and start/debug the application, and after a few seconds JVM crashes. Any ideas? Generated log is:

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0625665c, pid=19531, tid=2421361552
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode linux-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x25665c]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x080ff000):  JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=19544, stack(0x904b0000,0x90531000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x8a13e9ac, ECX=0x08929020, EDX=0xffffffff
ESP=0x9052ed80, EBP=0x9052edd8, ESI=0x8a13e978, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x0625665c, CR2=0x00000000, EFLAGS=0x00210202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x9052ed80)
0x9052ed80:   08929020 00000000 00000331 00000331
0x9052ed90:   9052eea0 8a7b2e64 00000000 9052eee0
0x9052eda0:   066a0bf0 ffffffff 0000000e 080966a8
0x9052edb0:   00000001 08929020 00000002 8a7b2e60
0x9052edc0:   00000011 9052f22c 01000312 000006fa
0x9052edd0:   9052eea0 9052f1c0 9052ef08 06255bb5
0x9052ede0:   9052f1c0 00000001 9052fb10 9052fb10
0x9052edf0:   0000010d 0000010d 9052ee38 9052f22c 

Instructions: (pc=0x0625665c)
0x0625664c:   5d dc 8b 03 53 8d 5e 34 ff 50 40 89 c7 8b 56 34
0x0625665c:   8b 00 21 c2 89 56 34 8b 47 04 8b 4b 04 21 c1 8b 

Stack: [0x904b0000,0x90531000],  sp=0x9052ed80,  free space=507k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x25665c]
V  [libjvm.so+0x255bb5]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2a2acd]
V  [libjvm.so+0x29f950]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2471e9]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2a6e3a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2a6846]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5b61ed]
V  [libjvm.so+0x4fe289]
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x54fb]


Current CompileTask:
C2:636      org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedMethodBinding.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedTypeBinding;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/MethodBinding;)V (596 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x08770400 JavaThread "btpool0-1" [_thread_blocked, id=19557, stack(0x8d206000,0x8d257000)]
  0x8e707400 JavaThread "Timer-1" [_thread_blocked, id=19552, stack(0x8ea79000,0x8eaca000)]
  0x08539400 JavaThread "btpool0-0 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080" [_thread_in_native, id=19551, stack(0x8f0ab000,0x8f0fc000)]
  0x082a3400 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19548, stack(0x8f05a000,0x8f0ab000)]
  0x08100800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19545, stack(0x9045f000,0x904b0000)]
=>0x080ff000 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=19544, stack(0x904b0000,0x90531000)]
  0x080fc800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=19543, stack(0x90531000,0x905b2000)]
  0x080fb800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19542, stack(0x905b2000,0x90603000)]
  0x080dfc00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19541, stack(0x90649000,0x9069a000)]
  0x080de800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19540, stack(0x9069a000,0x906eb000)]
  0x0805b800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=19532, stack(0xb7da7000,0xb7df8000)]

Other Threads:
  0x080db800 VMThread [stack: 0x906eb000,0x9076c000] [id=19539]
  0x08102000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x903de000,0x9045f000] [id=19546]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x08059558/0x08059580] VMOperationQueue_lock - owner thread: 0x0805b800
[0x08059998/0x080599b0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0805b800

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 38848K, used 21504K [0xb1370000, 0xb4c50000, 0xb4c50000)
  eden space 19456K, 100% used [0xb1370000,0xb2670000,0xb2670000)
  from space 19392K, 10% used [0xb2670000,0xb2870000,0xb3960000)
  to   space 19392K, 0% used [0xb3960000,0xb3960000,0xb4c50000)
 PSOldGen        total 96576K, used 69074K [0x94c50000, 0x9aaa0000, 0xb1370000)
  object space 96576K, 71% used [0x94c50000,0x98fc4878,0x9aaa0000)
 PSPermGen       total 26624K, used 15975K [0x90c50000, 0x92650000, 0x94c50000)
  object space 26624K, 60% used [0x90c50000,0x91be9e88,0x92650000)

Dynamic libraries:
06000000-0665d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1005378    /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.07/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so
0665d000-066a1000 rwxp 0065c000 08:03 1005378    /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.07/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so
066a1000-06ac3000 rwxp 066a1000 00:00 0 
08048000-08052000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1005321    /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.07/jre/bin/java
08052000-08053000 rwxp 00009000 08:03 1005321    /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.07/jre/bin/java
08053000-09d32000 rwxp 08053000 00:00 0          [heap]
89300000-893ec000 rwxp 89300000 00:00 0 
893ec000-89400000 ---p 893ec000 00:00 0 
89500000-89600000 rwxp 89500000 00:00 0 
89700000-897ff000 rwxp 89700000 00:00 0 
897ff000-89800000 ---p 897ff000 00:00 0 
89900000-899f0000 rwxp 89900000 00:00 0 
899f0000-89a00000 ---p 899f0000 00:00 0 
89a00000-89af9000 rwxp 89a00000 00:00 0 
89af9000-89b00000 ---p 89af9000 00:00 0 
89b00000-89bee000 rwxp 89b00000 00:00 0 
89bee000-89c00000 ---p 89bee000 00:00 0 
8a000000-8a0f9000 rwxp 8a000000 00:00 0 
8a0f9000-8a100000 ---p 8a0f9000 00:00 0 
8a100000-8a1ed000 rwxp 8a100000 00:00 0 
8a1ed000-8a200000 ---p 8a1ed000 00:00 0 
8a200000-8a2f9000 rwxp 8a200000 00:00 0 
8a2f9000-8a300000 ---p 8a2f9000 00:00 0 
8a300000-8a3f9000 rwxp 8a300000 00:00 0 
8a3f9000-8a400000 ---p 8a3f9000 00:00 0 
8a400000-8a4f9000 rwxp 8a400000 00:00 0 
8a4f9000-8a500000 ---p 8a4f9000 00:00 0 
8a500000-8a5f9000 rwxp 8a500000 00:00 0 
8a5f9000-8a600000 ---p 8a5f9000 00:00 0 
8a600000-8a6f9000 rwxp 8a600000 00:00 0 
8a6f9000-8a700000 ---p 8a6f9000 00:00 0 
8a700000-8a7f9000 rwxp 8a700000 00:00 0 
8a7f9000-8a800000 ---p 8a7f9000 00:00 0 
8a900000-8a9e1000 rwxp 8a900000 00:00 0 
8a9e1000-8aa00000 ---p 8a9e1000 00:00 0 
8aabb000-8ab00000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 954857     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
8ab00000-8ac00000 rwxp 8ab00000 00:00 0 
8ac3c000-8ac87000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 954858     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf
8ac87000-8ac88000 ---p 8ac87000 00:00 0 
8ac88000-8b488000 rwxp 8ac88000 00:00 0 
8b488000-8b4bc000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52538      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libmork.so
8b4bc000-8b4be000 rwxp 00034000 08:03 52538      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libmork.so
8b4be000-8b4c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52577      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libxpcom_compat_c.so
8b4c3000-8b4c4000 rwxp 00005000 08:03 52577      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libxpcom_compat_c.so
8b4c4000-8b4c5000 ---p 8b4c4000 00:00 0 
8b4c5000-8bcc5000 rwxp 8b4c5000 00:00 0 
8bcc5000-8bcc6000 ---p 8bcc5000 00:00 0 
8bcc6000-8c4c6000 rwxp 8bcc6000 00:00 0 
8c4c6000-8c4c7000 ---p 8c4c6000 00:00 0 
8c4c7000-8ccc7000 rwxp 8c4c7000 00:00 0 
8ccc7000-8ccca000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 620228     /lib/libgpg-error.so.0.3.0
8ccca000-8cccb000 rwxp 00002000 08:03 620228     /lib/libgpg-error.so.0.3.0
8cccb000-8cd16000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 620226     /lib/libgcrypt.so.11.2.3
8cd16000-8cd18000 rwxp 0004a000 08:03 620226     /lib/libgcrypt.so.11.2.3
8cd18000-8cd27000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 818392     /usr/lib/libtasn1.so.3.0.12
8cd27000-8cd28000 rwxp 0000e000 08:03 818392     /usr/lib/libtasn1.so.3.0.12
8cd28000-8cde7000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817682     /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0
8cde7000-8cdeb000 rwxp 000be000 08:03 817682     /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0
8cdeb000-8cdef000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817594     /usr/lib/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0
8cdef000-8cdf0000 rwxp 00003000 08:03 817594     /usr/lib/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0
8cdf0000-8cdf2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 637494     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libutil-2.7.so
8cdf2000-8cdf4000 rwxp 00001000 08:03 637494     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libutil-2.7.so
8cdf4000-8ce02000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 816254     /usr/lib/libavahi-client.so.3.2.4
8ce02000-8ce03000 rwxp 0000e000 08:03 816254     /usr/lib/libavahi-client.so.3.2.4
8ce03000-8ce0d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817895     /usr/lib/libavahi-common.so.3.5.0
8ce0d000-8ce0e000 rwxp 00009000 08:03 817895     /usr/lib/libavahi-common.so.3.5.0
8ce0e000-8ce7f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 816405     /usr/lib/libgnutls.so.13.9.1
8ce7f000-8ce84000 rwxp 00071000 08:03 816405     /usr/lib/libgnutls.so.13.9.1
8ce84000-8ceb8000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 820345     /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3.4.0
8ceb8000-8ceba000 rwxp 00033000 08:03 820345     /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3.4.0
8ceba000-8ced4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817785     /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.1.0
8ced4000-8ced5000 rwxp 0001a000 08:03 817785     /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.1.0
8ced5000-8cfef000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 818875     /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.6.31
8cfef000-8cff4000 rwxp 00119000 08:03 818875     /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.6.31
8cff4000-8cff5000 rwxp 8cff4000 00:00 0 
8cff5000-8cffc000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 620275     /lib/libpopt.so.0.0.0
8cffc000-8cffd000 rwxp 00006000 08:03 620275     /lib/libpopt.so.0.0.0
8cffd000-8d01f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817692     /usr/lib/libaudiofile.so.0.0.2
8d01f000-8d022000 rwxp 00021000 08:03 817692     /usr/lib/libaudiofile.so.0.0.2
8d022000-8d034000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817715     /usr/lib/libbonobo-activation.so.4.0.0
8d034000-8d036000 rwxp 00012000 08:03 817715     /usr/lib/libbonobo-activation.so.4.0.0
8d036000-8d087000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817713     /usr/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0.0.0
8d087000-8d091000 rwxp 00050000 08:03 817713     /usr/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0.0.0
8d091000-8d0e7000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817975     /usr/lib/libgnomevfs-2.so.0.2200.0
8d0e7000-8d0ea000 rwxp 00056000 08:03 817975     /usr/lib/libgnomevfs-2.so.0.2200.0
8d0ea000-8d0fe000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817945     /usr/lib/libgnome-2.so.0.2200.0
8d0fe000-8d0ff000 rwxp 00013000 08:03 817945     /usr/lib/libgnome-2.so.0.2200.0
8d0ff000-8d1ba000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52567      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libuconv.so
8d1ba000-8d1c0000 rwxp 000bb000 08:03 52567      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libuconv.so
8d1c0000-8d1ca000 rwxp 8d1c0000 00:00 0 
8d1cf000-8d1e4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52560      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libprofile.so
8d1e4000-8d1e5000 rwxp 00015000 08:03 52560      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libprofile.so
8d1e5000-8d1ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52741      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libxpcom_compat.so
8d1ff000-8d200000 rwxp 0001a000 08:03 52741      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libxpcom_compat.so
8d200000-8d205000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52565      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libtxmgr.so
8d205000-8d206000 rwxp 00004000 08:03 52565      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libtxmgr.so
8d206000-8d209000 ---p 8d206000 00:00 0 
8d209000-8d257000 rwxp 8d209000 00:00 0 
8d257000-8d25e000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52555      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libp3p.so
8d25e000-8d25f000 rwxp 00006000 08:03 52555      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libp3p.so
8d25f000-8d269000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52514      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libcookie.so
8d269000-8d26a000 rwxp 00009000 08:03 52514      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libcookie.so
8d26a000-8d26f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52743      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/plugins/libnullplugin.so
8d26f000-8d270000 rwxp 00004000 08:03 52743      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/plugins/libnullplugin.so
8d270000-8d299000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52522      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libgkplugin.so
8d299000-8d29b000 rwxp 00028000 08:03 52522      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libgkplugin.so
8d29b000-8d2b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52554      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/liboji.so
8d2b3000-8d2b4000 rwxp 00017000 08:03 52554      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/liboji.so
8d2b4000-8d2cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52725      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libjsj.so
8d2cd000-8d2cf000 rwxp 00018000 08:03 52725      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libjsj.so
8d2cf000-8d2d6000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52556      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libpipboot.so
8d2d6000-8d2d7000 rwxp 00007000 08:03 52556      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libpipboot.so
8d2d7000-8d34a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52508      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libappcomps.so
8d34a000-8d34d000 rwxp 00073000 08:03 52508      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libappcomps.so
8d34d000-8d399000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52515      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libdocshell.so
8d399000-8d39c000 rwxp 0004c000 08:03 52515      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libdocshell.so
8d39c000-8d3cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52519      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libgfx_gtk.so
8d3cd000-8d3cf000 rwxp 00031000 08:03 52519      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libgfx_gtk.so
8d3d2000-8d3d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817804     /usr/lib/libavahi-glib.so.1.0.1
8d3d4000-8d3d5000 rwxp 00001000 08:03 817804     /usr/lib/libavahi-glib.so.1.0.1
8d3d5000-8d3de000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817834     /usr/lib/libesd.so.0.2.38
8d3de000-8d3df000 rwxp 00008000 08:03 817834     /usr/lib/libesd.so.0.2.38
8d3e2000-8d3ed000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52531      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libjar50.so
8d3ed000-8d3ee000 rwxp 0000a000 08:03 52531      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libjar50.so
8d3ee000-8d447000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52523      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libhtmlpars.so
8d447000-8d44c000 rwxp 00058000 08:03 52523      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libhtmlpars.so
8d44c000-8d463000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52512      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libchrome.so
8d463000-8d464000 rwxp 00017000 08:03 52512      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libchrome.so
8d464000-8d475000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52573      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libwebbrwsr.so
8d475000-8d476000 rwxp 00011000 08:03 52573      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libwebbrwsr.so
8d476000-8d4be000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817590     /usr/lib/libORBit-2.so.0.1.0
8d4be000-8d4c8000 rwxp 00047000 08:03 817590     /usr/lib/libORBit-2.so.0.1.0
8d4c8000-8d4f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817879     /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
8d4f5000-8d4f8000 rwxp 0002d000 08:03 817879     /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
8d4f8000-8d520000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52575      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libwidget_gtk2.so
8d520000-8d523000 rwxp 00028000 08:03 52575      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libwidget_gtk2.so
8d523000-8d538000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817574     /usr/lib/libICE.so.6.3.0
8d538000-8d539000 rwxp 00014000 08:03 817574     /usr/lib/libICE.so.6.3.0
8d539000-8d53b000 rwxp 8d539000 00:00 0 
8d53b000-8d588000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817651     /usr/lib/libXt.so.6.0.0
8d588000-8d58c000 rwxp 0004c000 08:03 817651     /usr/lib/libXt.so.6.0.0
8d58d000-8d59a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52382      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/libgwt-ll.so
8d59a000-8d59b000 rwxp 0000d000 08:03 52382      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/libgwt-ll.so
8d59b000-8d5c4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52561      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/librdf.so
8d5c4000-8d5c6000 rwxp 00028000 08:03 52561      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/librdf.so
8d5c6000-8d5f3000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52525      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libimglib2.so
8d5f3000-8d5f4000 rwxp 0002d000 08:03 52525      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libimglib2.so
8d5f4000-8d62c000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52524      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libi18n.so
8d62c000-8d62f000 rwxp 00037000 08:03 52524      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libi18n.so
8d62f000-8d630000 ---p 8d62f000 00:00 0 
8d630000-8de30000 rwxp 8d630000 00:00 0 
8de30000-8de74000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52578      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libxpconnect.so
8de74000-8de77000 rwxp 00043000 08:03 52578      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libxpconnect.so
8de77000-8de78000 rwxp 8de77000 00:00 0 
8de78000-8e2f4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52521      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libgklayout.so
8e2f4000-8e32f000 rwxp 0047c000 08:03 52521      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libgklayout.so
8e32f000-8e335000 rwxp 8e32f000 00:00 0 
8e335000-8e3fa000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52548      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libnecko.so
8e3fa000-8e400000 rwxp 000c4000 08:03 52548      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libnecko.so
8e400000-8e500000 rwxp 8e400000 00:00 0 
8e501000-8e514000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52532      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libjsd.so
8e514000-8e515000 rwxp 00013000 08:03 52532      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libjsd.so
8e515000-8e52a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52511      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libcaps.so
8e52a000-8e52b000 rwxp 00014000 08:03 52511      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libcaps.so
8e52b000-8e53c000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817631     /usr/lib/libXft.so.2.1.2
8e53c000-8e53d000 rwxp 00010000 08:03 817631     /usr/lib/libXft.so.2.1.2
8e53d000-8e547000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 816836     /usr/lib/libpangox-1.0.so.0.2002.3
8e547000-8e548000 rwxp 00009000 08:03 816836     /usr/lib/libpangox-1.0.so.0.2002.3
8e548000-8e54e000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 816837     /usr/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.2002.3
8e54e000-8e54f000 rwxp 00005000 08:03 816837     /usr/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.2002.3
8e551000-8e558000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 817598     /usr/lib/libSM.so.6.0.0
8e558000-8e559000 rwxp 00006000 08:03 817598     /usr/lib/libSM.so.6.0.0
8e559000-8e55d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52724      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libgtkxtbin.so
8e55d000-8e55e000 rwxp 00003000 08:03 52724      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libgtkxtbin.so
8e55e000-8e56a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52728      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libmozz.so
8e56a000-8e56c000 rwxp 0000b000 08:03 52728      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libmozz.so
8e56c000-8e57d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52559      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libpref.so
8e57d000-8e57e000 rwxp 00011000 08:03 52559      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libpref.so
8e57e000-8e5fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52727      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libmozjs.so
8e5fc000-8e600000 rwxp 0007e000 08:03 52727      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libmozjs.so
8e600000-8e6df000 rwxp 8e600000 00:00 0 
8e6df000-8e700000 ---p 8e6df000 00:00 0 
8e700000-8e800000 rwxp 8e700000 00:00 0 
8e800000-8e8f9000 rwxp 8e800000 00:00 0 
8e8f9000-8e900000 ---p 8e8f9000 00:00 0 
8e900000-8e9f8000 rwxp 8e900000 00:00 0 
8e9f8000-8ea00000 ---p 8e9f8000 00:00 0 
8ea00000-8ea05000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52563      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libsystem-pref.so
8ea05000-8ea06000 rwxp 00005000 08:03 52563      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libsystem-pref.so
8ea06000-8ea15000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52566      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libtypeaheadfind.so
8ea15000-8ea16000 rwxp 0000e000 08:03 52566      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libtypeaheadfind.so
8ea16000-8ea41000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52517      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libembedcomponents.so
8ea41000-8ea43000 rwxp 0002a000 08:03 52517      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/components/libembedcomponents.so
8ea43000-8ea64000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52722      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libgkgfx.so
8ea64000-8ea65000 rwxp 00021000 08:03 52722      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/mozilla-1.7.12/libgkgfx.so
8ea65000-8ea78000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52385      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3235.so
8ea78000-8ea79000 rwxp 00012000 08:03 52385      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3235.so
8ea79000-8ea7c000 ---p 8ea79000 00:00 0 
8ea7c000-8eaca000 rwxp 8ea7c000 00:00 0 
8eaca000-8eb00000 r-xs 005cc000 08:03 25815      /home/toni/development/general_ws/HelloWorld/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.2.1.jar
8eb00000-8ebff000 rwxp 8eb00000 00:00 0 
8ebff000-8ec00000 ---p 8ebff000 00:00 0 
8ec00000-8ed00000 rwxp 8ec00000 00:00 0 
8ed00000-8edfa000 rwxp 8ed00000 00:00 0 
8edfa000-8ee00000 ---p 8edfa000 00:00 0 
8ee01000-8ee03000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 820803     /usr/lib/gconv/UTF-16.so
8ee03000-8ee05000 rwxp 00001000 08:03 820803     /usr/lib/gconv/UTF-16.so
8ee05000-8ee0a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 52387      /home/toni/development/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.linux_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-linux-1.6.4/libswt-mozilla17-profile-gtk-3235.so
8ee0a000-8ee0b0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exception, I just installed the latest VM release and now the compilation complete successfully :)

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/felog.html) on diagnosing JVM dumps may be of use. However, before you get to that:

1. can you recreate this reliably, or is it intermittent ? A one-off ?
2. are you using the latest VM release

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing the vanilla J2SDK from sun, if you haven't already.